# Catch image truncation event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there a way to catch the image corrupt or truncated error and handle it with javascript?

I have multiple gifs I'm trying to show on my website with a hover to animate feature. I first tried to just animate the src attribute on hover, but that was giving me image truncation errors, and would causes gifs to randomly break.

To try to get around that I am now creating a new img element and appending it to the dom, but this results in an annoying "flicker" when the images swap. code:

```
var gifs = document.getElementsByClassName("gif");

for(var i=0;i<gifs.length;i++){
        gifs[i].addEventListener('mouseenter', switchOn, false);
    }

var switchOn = function() {
    var oImg=document.createElement("img");
    var parent = this.parentElement;
    oImg.setAttribute('src', this.dataset.alt);
    oImg.setAttribute('data-alt', this.src);

    this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
    parent.appendChild(oImg);
    oImg.addEventListener('mouseleave', switchOff, false);
};

var switchOff = function() {
  var oImg=document.createElement("img");
  var parent = this.parentElement;
  oImg.setAttribute('src', this.dataset.alt);
  oImg.setAttribute('data-alt', this.src);

  this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
  parent.appendChild(oImg);
  oImg.addEventListener('mouseenter', switchOn, false);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

A common technique on seamless switching of images/gif/video is to actually render all asset elements to DOM but hide them with CSS. Then when switching you just hide and show with CSS based on your desired events. So with this example you would actually have two DOM elements on top of each other. One being the default image and the other being the alternate image. When a click happens you hide the default image and show the alternate image.

The problem with your flicker is mostly due to the fact that you are setting the source, which on a cache miss will actually have to download the image/gif/video before it will show anything.

This strategy will also fix your issue with gif's breaking. However the gifs could very well be in loop after you first show them. This is why html5 video tags are better options for this kind of functionality because you have full control of the seek.